# How to show data with small value on c3.js Donut

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, c3.js

I must implement a donut chart using c3 js library. 
I've a small issue with c3. When I have to include data with small value ( < 1% of the chart total value ) this value doesn't appear on the donut.

I've looked on the documentation of C3 but I've not found any information about a minimal value parameter for donuts.

Here is a example of the problem : https://jsfiddle.net/g5hyxr61/

```
['accountH', 0.27]
```

On the example the last value (0.27) doesn't appear. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: It does appear, if you click on the legend and mute everything but accountH you will see that it is there (or if you hover between accountG and accountA), but since it is so small, the value shows as ~0.0% I am not sure how you should handle this, since it is not like you should change the value...

Comment: The thing is the value is not only < 1% of the total value, it is < 0.001%, so it is reasonable that it doesn't appear. Even if you compare it with the smallest group (4874) it will be insignificant.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "threshold" option, like:

```
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['DataA', 200],
            ['DataB', 1200],
            ['accountC', 50]
        ],
        type : 'donut'
    },
    donut: {
      label: {
        threshold: 0.01
      }
    }
```